# How to delete row using ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

How to delete a record in php mysql using the AJAX.

here's the code:

***delete_record.php***

```
<?php
    require_once "../include/connection.php";

    if ($_REQUEST['rowid']) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM lesson1 WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['rowid']."'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) {
            //echo "Success";
        } else {
            //echo "Error: $sql";
            mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
    myqli_close($conn);
?>
```

***index.php***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowId = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '#btnDel', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        rowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
      });

      $('#accDelBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'delete_record.php',
          data: 'rowid=' + rowId,
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Records were deleted successfully');
            $('#modalDelete').modal('hide');
          }
        });
      })
    });
    </script>
```

what I'm trying to here is to delete a record.
when I'm clicking the delete. message is success but the data is not deleted.

Comment: That code is extraordinary dangerous. Do not write code like that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad why sir? sorry its my first time to using the php.

Comment: Dangerous because if someone adds rowid value equals to '1111111' OR true. This will delete every row in your table. Try it obviously with a backup database.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen but the id is auto increment.

Comment: No but you should use something like prepared statements. Also I am not sure but I suspect the problem could be that your ids in the database table are integer values but in the $sql variable your are setting it as string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Print a message or rowid within:
   `if ($_REQUEST['rowid']) {}`
2. Check the query in MySQL browser
3. Check the connection string